# How to call a java class from reactjs app

Tags: java, database, reactjs

I have a reactjs app that needs to get data. There is a java class that connects to the database and gets data. Can I call this java class from my react app? I'm a complete newbie with react. Reading and working on my first app.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

Java would be your backend. You need to make a webservice (for instance, a rest service).

Then you would call that service from your React app (your front end).

You can make a rest webservice with pretty much any technology / framework. Something like Spring will get you up and running in 5 minutes: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Complete tutorial using Spring + React: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/

Comment: I don't know Spring or Maven. Any other technology/framework?

Comment: You don't really need much to learn to just create a webservice to return some data. The first link I gave you will get you on your feet in just 15 minutes if this is your first time. The maven side will be just copy / paste some lines for you. The spring side is super documented. If you still want other frameworks, would be best to know what you know instead of me throwing options. I would still argue Spring or Spring Boot is the most balanced and easy framework to pick up.